# Кодировка по умолчанию для компилятора языка Java (Javac)

Tags: java, кодировка, компиляция, unicode, компилятор

Столкнулся с одним интересным вопросом. Вводил одного своего товарища в азы программирования и столкнулся с определённой коллизией. Всегда был уверен в том, что стандартный компилятор языка Java (Javac), который поставляется в составе многих JDK, в частности в составе Oracle JDK, определяет кодировку любого Java-файла, как UTF-8, если мы не даём ему явным образом понять, что дело имеется с какой-либо другой кодировкой. Мы конечно же могли бы сделать это при помощи параметра -encoding, но никто не обязует нас этого делать, если нас устраивает то поведение, которому компилятор подчиняется по умолчанию.

И вроде бы всё работало нормально, пока я не решил попробовать сохранить Java-файл в кодировке UTF-8 с использованием маркера последовательности байтов (BOM), который явно указывает на тот факт, что наш файл закодирован именно при помощи данного стандарта кодирования. Напомню, что для кодировки UTF-8, данный специальный символ состоит из неразрывной трёхбайтовой последовательности, которую можно представить в шестнадцатиричной форме, как `EF BB BF`. Это конечно совершенно необязательно, да и поведение компилятора было вполне ожидаемым, так как я понимал, что он не ожидает этого символа и скорее всего не сможет определить его должным образом и выдаст соответствующую ошибку. При этом, результат немного удивил и заставил задуматься над вопросом, а действительно ли комплятор определяет нашу кодировку, как UTF-8? При попытке компиляции получил следующую ошибку:

```
$:javac Test.java 
Test.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
 public class Test {
^
1 error
```

Если транслятор знает, что мы используем UTF-8, то почему он определил наш символ, как `U+00BB`, а не `U+FEFF`, который у нас на самом деле используется? Мне кажется, что в таком случае компилятор должен был выдать ошибку типа:

```
Test.java:1: error: illegal character: '\ufeff'
```

Кто может объяснить подобное поведение компилятора и какую кодировку он воспринимает по умолчанию? Думаю, что вопрос интересный и было бы неплохо с этим разобраться! Благодарю всех за помощь!

Comment: По умолчанию компилятор использует системную кодировку.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а где её можно посмотреть? Это случайно не значение системного параметра ACP, который находится в разделе HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage, если смотреть через редактор реестра? Или где-то в другом месте нужно смотреть? Если что, то использую Windows 10 Enterprise x86-64 version 1909 (OS build: 18363.778) на английском языке.

Comment: В Windows это всегда cp1251 или cp1252.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, интересно получается. Да, в ОС семейства Windows всегда использовались кодировки Windows-125x в зависимости от региона, это я знаю, но теперь ситуация немного поменялась. В той же Википедии указано, что кодировка Windows-1251 использовалась для русских версий Microsoft Windows вплоть до 10-й версии. В каком-то из глобальных обновлений для Windows 10 в разделе системных настроек «Region» во вкладке «Administrative», если нажать на кнопку «Change system locale...», то откроется окно «Region Settings», где появился дополнительный параметр, которого раньше никогда не было.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, он находится на стадии Beta-тестирования и называется «Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support», технически представляющий собой checkbox, который по умолчанию уже активирован.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, проверил также параметр ACP в системном реестре, там у меня выставлено значение 65001, что является идентификатором кодировки UTF-8 в операционных системах семейства Windows. И я вот думаю... Если у меня всё-таки стоит по умолчанию UTF-8 и компилятор воспринимает содержимое исходного файла, как текст, который закодирован именно в этой кодировке, то почему у меня появилась именно это ошибка? Откуда взялся пресловутый символ '\u00bb', хотя в начале был обычный BOM в совокупности с кодировкой UTF-8? Опять-таки возвращаемся к самой сути вопроса...

Comment: Даже с правильной кодировкой, javac будет реагировать на BOM ошибкой. [Соответствующий баг](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4508058), которому уже 19 лет и который никогда не будет исправлен.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Благодарю, немного повозился и вроде бы разобрался в данном вопросе! Спасибо за то, что направили в нужное русло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, в моей системе всё содержимое файлов, которые я подавал на вход стандартному компилятору Java (Javac), воспринималось в кодировке Windows-1251, в качестве исходной. Это было выяснено экспериментальным путём и несколько раз подтверждено. Что интересно, именно эта кодировка является стандартной в моём случае, даже несмотря на то, что моя операционная система, а у меня стоит `Windows 10 Enterprise x86-64 version 10.0.18363.778 (Win10 19H2 [1909] November 2019 Update)`, устанавливалась с английского дистрибутива и не содержала дополнительных языковых пакетов. Кроме того, в региональных настройках у меня включена опция `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support`, которая предполагает использование UTF-8 в качестве стандартной кодировки, если я правильно понял смысл этого параметра. Тем не менее, полагаю, что кодировка Windows-1251 используется по той причине, что на этапе первоначальной установки операционный системы, в качестве текущего формата времени и денежных единиц, была выбрана Россия с её параметром «Русский (Россия)».

Когда я запускал программу, которая была сохранена в кодировке UTF-8 с маркером последовательности байтов, то происходило примерно следующее. Поскольку я был уверен в том, что в качестве исходной кодировки и так будет использован UTF-8, то не стал использовать параметр -encoding и явно указывать на эту кодировку. На самом же деле файл обрабатывался в кодировке Windows-1251, что немного ввело в ступор, так как та ошибка, на которую указывал компилятор, была не совсем очевидной, если его поведение понимается ошибочно. Поскольку по умолчанию использовалась кодировка Windows-1251, представляющая собой однобайтовую кодовую страницу, то компилятор воспринимал нашу 3-байтовую последовательность в самом начале, как 3 отдельных символа, а не как один, что собственно и было задумано. Итак, последовательность `EF BB BF` читалась компилятором, как следующий набор символов: `п»ї`. К символам `п` и `ї` особых вопросов у нашего транслятора не возникло, так как эти символы могут быть частью (и даже началом) вполне корректного токена. Речь идёт об идентификаторах, которые могут состоять, в том числе и из символов различных кириллических алфавитов. А вот с правой французской кавычкой (right-pointing double angle quotation mark, `»`, U+00BB) дела обстоят немного иначе. Дело в том, что этот символ не может быть частью корректных лексических токенов и может использоваться, разве что, как составляющая строковой константы. Именно по этой причине, находясь почти в любом месте в коде, он вызовет ошибку `error: illegal character: '\u00bb'`, а про другие символы и их не совсем удачные сочетания, компилятор предпочтёт позабыть до лучших времён.

Что же касается самого бага, который действительно имеет место, то он распространяется не только на UTF-8, но и на другие кодировки. К примеру, если мы используем кодировку с указанием последовательности байтов (UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE, UTF-32LE) и сам маркер последовательности для соответствующей кодировки (тот самый BOM или `U+FEFF`), то можно увидеть, что компилятор всё равно не хочет его никак понимать и будет целенаправленно ругаться. Даже если мы всегда будем указывать верную кодировку и использовать параметр -encoding с соответствующим значением, то всё равно будем получать одну и ту же ошибку (разумеется в том случае, если в самом начале файла у нас будет идти BOM): `error: illegal character: '\ufeff'` (или `'\ufffe'`, в случае перестановки байтов местами).

Ну и выводы, которые я для себя сделал. Не стоит использовать BOM в Java-файлах, очевидно, что компилятор с ним не дружит. Всегда использовать параметр -encoding, даже в тех случаях, когда этого можно было бы избежать, так будет намного спокойнее и понятнее. А ещё я понял, что не стоит надеяться на то, что данный баг хоть когда-нибудь пофиксят. Если этого не сделали за 19 лет, то скорее всего не сделают уже никогда.

Хочу поблагодарить [@SergeyGornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev) за правильную наводку.

**P.S.** Хотелось внести небольшое дополнение относительно стандартов кодирования Unicode UTF-16 и UTF-32. Похоже, что вышеуказанный баг распространяется только на UTF-8, а с UTF-16 и UTF-32 немного иная ситуация. Провёл небольшую серию тестов и вроде бы сумел разобраться в этом деле. Если мы используем маркер последовательности байтов (`U+FEFF`) и в качестве декодирования предлагаем ориентироваться компилятору на UTF-16 или UTF-32 (без указания порядка следования байтов), то компилятор адекватно будет обрабатывать наш BOM, так как мы не указали в наших кодировках порядок байтов, а определять его как-то нужно (если нет маркера в начале потока, то по умолчанию используется порядок от старшего к младшему (англ. big-endian — большим концом)). Другое дело, когда мы ясно даём понять, что декодирование необходимо производить из UTF-16BE/LE и UTF-32BE/LE. В этом случае никакой BOM уже не нужен и вне зависимости от того, как он будет записан и будет ли присутствовать вообще, компилятор будет декодировать байты в том порядке, который диктует ему конкретная кодировка. Вот в этих случаях начинают вылазить ошибки. Дело в самом символе `'\ufeff'`, который в противном случае считается уже не маркером последовательности байтов, а неразрывным пробелом нулевой ширины (zero-width non-breaking space). Использовать его можно в качестве какого-нибудь строкового литерала, но если он появляется не там где нужно, то это вызывает ошибку. В отличие от пробельных символов, он не является "незначащим" и уже не игнорируется просто так компилятором. Так что данный баг целиком и полностью имеет отношение исключительно к UTF-8.

Comment: Вообще вместо Windows-1251 с таким же успехом может быть и Latin-1, так как в ней байт `BB` декодируется в ту же кавычку. Впрочем, сути дела это не меняет

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю Вас за комментарий! Сразу могу сказать, что в моём случае используется именно Windows-1251 и для меня это стало очевидным тогда, когда я попытался скомпилировать программу в кодировке Windows-1252. Тогда я получил результат, который отличался от того, который я получал в том случае, когда не использовал параметр -encoding вообще. Кодировки Windows-1252 и ISO/IEC 8859-1 (она же "Latin alphabet no. 1" или latin1) фактически идентичны (совпадают на 76,09 %, что соответствует 191-му символу в абсолютной величине).

Comment: @andreymal Позиции, которые находятся в диапазоне с 0x0020-0x007E и 0x00A0-0x00FF полностью совпадают с одними и теми же абстрактными символами в обеих кодировках. Поскольку обе кодировки являются однобайтовыми, то в процессе декодирования компилятор интерпретировал бы байтовую последовательность, которая в UTF-8 представляет один символ (тот самый BOM), как 3 отдельных символа. И это уже не будет не последователость `п»ї`, а `ï»¿`. Разница, конечно, не является какой-то принципиальной, но на результат компиляции уже повлияет.

Comment: @andreymal В этом случае компилятор ругнётся не только на кавычку, но ещё и на перевёрнутый знак вопроса, который также не может быть частью корректного лексического токена в языке программирования Java. При использовании кодировки Windows-1252 или ISO/IEC 8859-1:1998 компилятор выдаёт следующую ошибку (точнее целых две): `$:javac -encoding latin1 Test.java
Test.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
??public class Test {
 ^
Test.java:1: error: illegal character: '\u00bf'
??public class Test {
  ^
2 errors

` 
Так что таким вот "лабораторным путём" удалось докопаться до истины!)